# Updating hexadecimal values in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, hex, ascii, special-characters

I have extra characters in my table 'XYZ'. I am comparing the data of this table with other tables. Now XYZ has some extra characters and I want to update the hexadecimal values in other tables. How can I write an update statement for this in DB2 ?

For example : I have character with hex value : `4C6F6E646F6E`, I am trying regex to replace 6E to 6F like this :

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('LONDON', '\x6E','\x6F') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

Comment: Show us please your queries - what have you already tried?

Comment: @Rubecka Provide some data sample for all participating tables and the result desired.

Comment: For example :
I have character with hex value : 4C6F6E646F6E, I am trying regex to replace 6E to 6F like this : SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('LONDON', '\x6E','\x6F') FROM 
    SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] your question. Do not use comments to clarify; comments may or may not be shown in any order. Code is hard to read in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try either of the following equivalent expressions:

```
SELECT
  STR_ORIG
, STR_REPL
, HEX(STR_ORIG) HEX_ORIG
, HEX(STR_REPL) HEX_REPL
FROM
(
SELECT 
  T.STR STR_ORIG
--, REGEXP_REPLACE(T.STR, x'6E', x'6F')  STR_REPL
, REGEXP_REPLACE(T.STR, '\x6E', x'6F')  STR_REPL
FROM (VALUES 'London') T (STR)
);

|STR_ORIG|STR_REPL     |HEX_ORIG    |HEX_REPL                  |
|--------|-------------|------------|--------------------------|
|London  |Loodoo       |4C6F6E646F6E|4C6F6F646F6F              |
```